# How to locally update a component after changing it's source?

Tags: joomla-3.x

**SOLVED: I have been changing the source file in the WRONG folder. I have been changing the component in the "component/" folder instead of "administrator/"**

I've changed the component's source file which changes a single label in the backend (administrative) side.
However after the change and upload I don't see the change being applied.

I've cleared Joomla cache as well as the browsers cache, but to no avail.

Is there a way to force Joomla 3.6 to reload the changed PHP file?

***EDIT ***

I'm changing a source file that's in the "/components/com_component/helpers/layouts" folder. Here is an extract of the file:

```
<tr>
    <td class="key" >
        <?php echo JText::_('OS_CLIMATE')?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini" name="climate" id="climate" size="5" value="<?php echo $row->climate;?>"> kg/m
    </td>
</tr>
```

This is part of a backend layout where you can change properties of an item. It can be accessed at this URL: "administrator/index.php?option=com_component&task=properties_edit&cid[]=2"

I have been changing various HTML text (like "kg/m" to "Hello!"), uploading the source file back to the aforementioned folder and going to the URL. But nothing changes!

I've even deleted the whole file, and it's like it's still there. Do you think some source filed of Joomla components get copied somewhere on install/update?

I can change the frontend stuff freely, but the backend stuff doesn't update when I change it.

Comment: Without wanting to come across as sharp, people are going to need a lot more detail before they can help you. At a minimum you should edit your post to specify what component file you've changed and a little bit more info on what you're trying to do. As things stand I don't know whether you're attempting a layout override, building your own component or even (God forbid) modifying core Joomla files - you shouldn't need to locally update a component, Joomla should be loading the correct file itself if you've done things properly.

Comment: @Creak I have installed a component and now I'm modifying the backend UI part of it. I want to change a single HTML label.

Comment: @Howie - please write your solution as a proper answer below and mark it as "solved"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been changing the source file in the WRONG folder. I have been changing the component in the "component/" folder instead of "administrator/"

Comment: Now you've added the answer you should accept it - if memory serves you'll get some internet points for doing so too. ;)

Comment: @Creak Unfortunately, stackexchange withholds internet points for 2 whole days when answering your own question! :(